# How to show selected items in multiple select Box

Tags: php, mysql, html

This is my mutiple select drop down box in edit page. Problem here is that this shows only one selected items. It doesn't show all selected items in it. How can i correct this?

```
    <?php
         $query="SELECT * FROM lab";
        $dropdown = "<select name='labid[]' multiple='multiple'  style='height:80px;' size='5' id='lab'>";
        //$dropdown .= "<option value=''>Select lab to assign </option>";
        $result2 = mysql_query ($query);
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) 
        {

  $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row2['lab_id']}'";
            while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) 
              {
                 if(($row1['lab_id'])==($row2['lab_id']))
                  {
                      $dropdown .=" selected='selected'";
                  }
             }
  $dropdown .= ">{$row2['l_name']}</option>";
        }
        $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
        echo $dropdown;
       ?>
```

Comment: i think it is not selecting even a single item. right?

Comment: no its selecting only the 1st item (in db)

Comment: you should `echo` the `$row1['lab_id'], $row2['lab_id']` and check their values for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

try to change that while loop into a foreach loop.

Change

```
 while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
```

to

```
foreach(mysql_fetch_assoc($result2) as $row2)
```

and

```
 while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
```

to

```
foreach(mysql_fetch_assoc($result1) as $row1)
```

Comment: :) seems this is a good approach. But Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error occurred @ second foreach loop. {while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) }

Comment: @viddz: That error may be caused by $result1 not being declared. You must declare $result1 in your snippet.